# How do i tell ELRte to not remove my <head>, <title> etc. tags?

Tags: javascript, elrte

ELRte is a great WYSIWYG editor, but it assumes too much responsibilities ...

especially in stripping tags from my content.

the most annoying is when i try to save a layout and it is removing all my ,   tags!

can not find a viable option in there wiki/docs to prohibit this behavior.

any clues on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a unofficial way of doing this:

```
elRTE.prototype.options.denyTags = [];
```

by default, `denyTags` are populated with all the tags they consider should be removed.

setting it to an empty array will result in removing no tags.

if you yet have some tags you need removed, add them to array, like:

```
elRTE.prototype.options.denyTags = ['applet', 'base', 'basefont', 'bgsound', 'etc...'];
```